# Ext JS make paging toolbar smaller

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, extjs

I have a very simple question but I don't seem to find a simple answer. In fact, I haven't found any answer how to make the paging toolbar of a Ext JS grid smaller.

I made a very simple [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1bl1) to investigate how this works, and it looks like at some point ExtJS will dynamically calculate the positions of the elements in the paging toolbar. Specifically the 'left' css attributes are set.

So I would like to know how to tweak the function that calculates these values so I can decrease these values. I could use jQuery/Javascript to do this but that just sounds so wrong so I prefer a clean ExtJS way to  do this.

So instead of something like this...

[image]

I would like to see this:

[image]

For instance, the 'previous page' button in my sample has an inline css style declared (most likely done by the paging toolbar widget) with 41px to left whereas the separator icon has 81px for the same 'left' style. This goes on until the entire width of the toolbar is covered.

So to conclude, what I want is to intercept the calculations and decrease the values of the elements to lower the entire width of the toolbar.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: So you want to move your button to the right? Or do you want to reduce the size of this toolbar? (Both the height of the toolbar and the button are editable)

Comment: @Ludovic I want to reduce the size of the toolbar, so squeeze the elements together a little bit more.

Comment: So you just have to reduce the size of your toolbar or the size of every elements in it with the `height` property

Comment: The horizontal position gets set by measuring the items and then placing them.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Right, so what do you suggest then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I'd post the answer to my own question. There's a config that enables horizontal scrolling when the toolbar gets too small:

```
Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', { 
   overflowHandler: 'scroller'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First set the width of your button.

```
new Ext.Button({
   width: 100,   <<== width of the button
   text: 'Smaller paging toolbar',
   // ...
```

Then you can move your element to the right with a Toolbar Separator just before your button :

```
[
   {xtype: 'tbseparator', width: 200 },
   new Ext.Button({
   // ...
```

Here is your [corrected fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/1j7e)

Comment: That doesn't seem to have any effect, and I'm quite surprised by youranswer. Why would the height have any effect on the width of the individual items in the toolbar?

Comment: @hbulens You are right i misunderstood your question. See my edited answer

Comment: That is no way near an answer to my question.

Comment: @hbulens So i still do not understand your question, can you explain it with another smaller example... What do you really want to achieve here?

Comment: @hbulens you want to decrease the *left* value. What does that mean? The button is already on the left in your example

Comment: I'm talking about the style of the elements in the toolbar. Every member of the paging toolbar has a certain 'left' style expressed in pixels. See updated question.

Comment: @hbulens Got it! Sorry to misunderstood you :) I think this is only CSS and not internal code that set this margin.